# <UL> basesd on common id fetch from databse

Tags: php, while-loop

I'm trying to iterate through my array and group li's with their relative ul, based on a common id.

expected result is as follows

```
<ul>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>g</li>
<li>e</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>d</li>
<li>f</li>
<li>i</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>d</li>
<li>f</li>
<li>i</li>
</ul>
```

I have tried following code

```
<?php
$IMPLODED_trid = 1,2,3,4,5,6 ;
$result=mysqli_query('SELECT * FROM tablegroup where id IN ($IMPLODED_trid)');
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$name=$row['name'];
?>
<ul>
<li><?php $name ;?></li>
</ul>
<?php
}
?>
```

but above code gives following result

```
<ul>
<li>c</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>a</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>d</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>i</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you give us an example of what the SQL query results in? Just run it in your DBMS instead of from PHP so you can look at the output. From the output I can tell it only contains four rows, with `name` set to `c`, `a`, `d` and `i`. I cant tell more since I don't know your table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong. Put `ul` tag out of the body of `while` loop. Try this:

```
<ul>
    <?php
    $IMPLODED_trid = 1,2,3,4,5,6 ;
    $result=mysqli_query('SELECT * FROM tablegroup where id IN ($IMPLODED_trid)');
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $name=$row['name'];
        ?>
        <li><?php $name ;?></li>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: @itsoftware I just corrected  your code. I didnt knew what was the structure of your db. I dont know sql, so posting what is inside `$row` should be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use two loops.

One outer for generating the `<ul>` elements, another for generating the `<li>` elements *within* the `<ul>`

Such code might look like this

```
<?php
    $result = []; //grouped by ul ID

    for ($i = 1; $i < count($ids); $i++) {
        echo '<ul>';
        while ($row = $result[$i])
            echo '<li>' . $result[$i]['name'] . '</li>';
        echo '</ul>';
    }
?>
```

It's valid PHP but it doesn't work ofcourse.
This is the structure you're looking for tho since you'll want an outer loop to go through the amount of `<ul>` elements you need and within that loop you'll want to loop through the list-items themselves.

The outer loop wouldn't be needed if you only had one `<ul>` ofcourse.